# How to get a specific date type in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using the below method to get this string `to_date('2011/06/02','yyyy/mm/dd')`

```
private static String getOperationDate() {
  Date today= new Date();
  String output;
  SimpleDateFormat formatter;
  String pattern="yyyy/MM/dd";

  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
  output = formatter.format(today);
  String temp="to_date('"+output+"','yyyy/mm/dd')";

  return temp;
}
```

How can i generate something like this `to_date('2011-05-27 12:45:56.1',....)` i.e., apart from just date how can i also include time with milliseconds, which would then be updated to the database

**Added a oracle** insert statement, after referring to an answer by `trutheality`, but this gives me `01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"` error

```
INSERT INTO CONFIG_INFO(CFG_ID,CFG_NAME,CFG_DESC,CFG_TYPE,FILE_NAME,ABSOLUTE_PATH,EMAIL_ADDRESS,PROJECT_ID,HOSTNAME,CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE,STATE,PRODUCT_ID)
    VALUES (config_seq.NEXTVAL,'Abhishek','as','Production','asdclient1.xml','E:tomcat 5.5bin/../webapps/asd/files/asdclient.xml','a@a.com','ABC','abhinix',to_date('2011/06/02 11:18:38.211','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),to_date('2011/06/02 11:18:38.211','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),2,123456)
```

Comment: This should not be necessary -- the JDBC driver provides classes to map an Oracle DATE data type to a Java Date and vice versa.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks for your reply, in my case i am generating a query which takes `temp` as a bind parameter

Comment: I comprehend what you are attempting to do, but I want to really stress that it's not a recommended approach.  I wish you luck

Comment: @OMG Ponies: can you refer me any link or any sample of what should i be doing, that would be really helpfull :)

Comment: Here you go Simon http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and figure out what your format string should be.

Probably something like

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
```

But the proper way is to use the JDBC driver as OMG Ponies has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old thread, but I've just faced a similar problem with the same error message. The nice solution has already been found, but I think my finding does worth to be mentioned.

For me, the basic problem in the expression that's being generated:

```
to_date('2011/06/02 11:18:38','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
```

because the code for minutes is different for oracle (where the expression will be evaluated) than java:: 'mi' should be used, as 'mm' is reserved for months (upper and lowercase doesn't really matter, the referenced documentation is rather about java than sql).
The error message you get is about the double reference to the 'mm' parameter, which should be avoided. A proper usage is something like this:

```
to_date('2011/06/02 11:18:38','yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, my answer has nothing to do with java, I shouldn't have mention it, as it caused some confusion.
I was talking about the to_date sql function. The error message is thrown for the insert statement pasted at the very end of the question, and it suffers from this issue.
To put this in other wording, the problem is not with variable `pattern` in java code, rather with `temp`, which gets returned, and I suppose, later run as part of an sql insert.

Comment: OK. I edited the answer to make that clear, and gave you a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 private static String getOperationDate() {
 Date today= new Date();
 String output;
 SimpleDateFormat formatter;
 String pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";

 formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
 output = formatter.format(today);
 String temp="to_date('"+output+"','yyyy/mm/dd')";

 return temp;
}
```